# xslt:1.0 - Using xslt, how to rename the element name and strip blank spaces correctly

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<update-this>
<document name="http://blah">
<amount>015-39</amount>
<shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
<c:karoke:string>abcabc</c:karoke:string>
<size>11.5 D</size>
<price>100.00 USD</price>
<stock>present in stock </stock>
</document>
</update-this>
```

This is how I want my final XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document name="http://blah">
<amount>015-39</amount>
<shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
<karoke>abcabc</karoke>
<size>11.5 D</size>
<price>100.00 USD</price>
<stock>present in stock </stock>
<size_stock>11.5D_presentinstock</size_stock>
<size_present>11.5D_present>
<discounted_price>90 USD</discounted_price>
<increased_price>110 USD</increased_price>
</document>
```

This is the XSLT-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:variable name="price" select="substring-before(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currency" select="substring-after(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="difference" select="number($price) * .10"/>
        <xsl:variable name="size">
        <xsl:value-of select="size"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="stock">
         <xsl:value-of select="stock"/>
         </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <discounted_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price - $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></discounted_price>
            <increased_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price + $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></increased_price>
            <size_stock> <xsl:value-of select="concat($size,'_',$stock)" /></size_stock>
            <size_present><xsl:value-of select="concat($size,'_','present')" /></size_present>
        </xsl:copy>
         <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(name(), 'c:karoke:string')">
            <xsl:element name="karoke">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
           </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="size_stock | size_present">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using XSLT 1.0, my XML has multiple document element. Why is the rename of the element c:karoke:string to just karoke not working? Also, the blank spaces in size_stock and size_present are not getting removed. Can you please help me?

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML!

Comment: Specifically, `<c:karoke:string>abcabc</c:karoke:string>` is not well-formed.   Changing that to, for example, `<c-karoke-string>abcabc</c-karoke-string>` would correct your input XML, which is minimally necessary to proceed to consider any further problems in your XSLT.

Comment: But that is how my input is @kjhughes....

Comment: Then your input does not qualify as being XML, and you cannot expect to use XML tools to process it.

Comment: @kjhughes thanks! I am clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
 <xsl:when test="starts-with(name(), 'c:karoke:string')">
```

you are in the context of:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
```

Therefore the `name()` function will return the string `"document"` which does not start with `'c:karoke:string'` so this test will never return true.

Comment: @Meow If that's your input, then your code cannot be "corrected".

Comment: thanks. So, you mean to say that we cannot replace element c:blah:string with just blah? But that is how my input is, and i need to replace such elements like c:blah:string with just blah.

Comment: `c:blah:string` is not a valid element name.